# Why when adding processes to dataGridView1 i see only 9 processes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When im running windows rask manager i see many processes/apps .
But in my program i see only 9 .

```
void PopulateApplications()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();           
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                    ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                    ima.Save(@"c:\temp\ima.jpg");
                    String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima,p.ProcessName, status);
                    DoubleBuffered1(dataGridView1, true);
                }
            }
            firsttime += 1;
            if (firsttime == 1)
            {
                NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            }
            if (NumberOfRows != dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            {
                int diff = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - NumberOfRows;
                this.Height = this.Height + (ROW_SIZE * diff);
                NumberOfRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            }

        }
```

I loop over the processes and add a row for each process and it's icon.
But i see only 9 processes in the dataGridView1.

How can i add all the processes/apps to the dataGridView1 rows like in task manager ?
How can i find get a list of procsesses that are allways runinng by the system those i can't close but that are running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because many processes are background ones / run without any Window attached, so the [MainWindowTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle) will be empty (`string.Empty` to be correct), and your test `if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)` would return `false` for all those processes.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle) says:

> If the associated process does not have a main window (so that MainWindowHandle is zero), MainWindowTitle is an empty string ("").

Comment: quantdev then what windows rask manager show when i run it ? He show a lot of processes/apps.

Comment: Have you looked at `Process.ProcessName` ? Can you confirm problem fixed ?

Comment: Yes then how i do i t and get all the icons ?

Comment: I use ProcessName here: dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima,p.ProcessName, status);

Comment: Simply don't do the test `if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)` . 

Also you should test the string `p.MainModule.FileName` before retrieving the Icon, some processes have no icon. Remember to accept answers please.